# Can't find the values of my variable

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So I have a login page and I am trying to display the values of the `$usercheck` and `$passwordcheck` that I made but they won't show

```
<?php 
 include_once ('includes/head.php');
if(isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `id`, `password`, `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :8gEwsko93_37554d ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1");
    $query->bindValue(":email", $email);
    $query->bindValue(":8gEwsko93_37554d", $password);
    $query->execute();

    $passwordcheck = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($query->rowCount() == 0){
    echo "No user";
    } else {
    if($passwordcheck == $password) {

    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :8gZwsZo93_3Z5Zs4d ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1");
    $query->bindValue(":email", $email);
    $query->bindValue(":8gZwsZo93_3Z5Zs4d", $password);
    $query->execute(); 

    $usercheck = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($passwordcheck);
    var_dump($usercheck);
    }
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try looking under the bed?

Comment: Is that a joke or ? @TheBlueDog

Comment: Yeah, sorry 'bout that ... :)

Comment: Where is your code getting stuck? What is your output? And what did you expect?

Comment: I expect for the values of the table to be returned @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Comment: If my answer answers your question (which I think it should) please award the answer so I get the reputation points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At line 17 in your example, you're comparing `$passwordcheck`, which is a result of `$query->fetch()` [thus possibly an array, since it fetches whole row] with `$password`, which is string. Such comparison is always false for nonempty `$password`. Thus your section with `print_r()` is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
if($passwordcheck == $password)
```

To

```
   if($passwordcheck['password'] == $password)
```

Where 'password' is the column name

Comment: If this solves your problem, you should mark this answer as solution